# CSS: remove underline from text

Tags: css

I have the following HTML

```
<div style="text-decoration: underline;">
    outer text
    <div style="text-decoration: none;">inner text</div>
</div>
```

Even though I used "none" for "inner text", it is still underlined. Here is the JS fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/oj2wj1d6/1/

How can I remove the underline from "inner text"? I have to maintain the same HTML structure without adding any new HTML tags.

Comment: wow. even `!important` doesn't work. :(

Comment: maybe there's a way through javascript ...

Comment: maybe a coherent markup would avoid this http://jsfiddle.net/oj2wj1d6/8/ or even http://jsfiddle.net/oj2wj1d6/9/  out of context answers are guesses

Comment: having no idea why its not working.. But when you change the property order means           first div contain none and second have underline then its work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of hacky but using the `::first-line` psueduo selector, it applies the style to the 'first line' only so in the example below I used an element (a `p`) to break the text and trigger the action.

*This is of course assuming that the only text you want to be underlined is the first line of your content. caveat emptor, YMMV, etc.*

[example on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/kqszy3gp/1/)

html:

```
<div class="first-line-underline">
  outer text a sentence
  wut
  yea
  <p>inner text</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.first-line-underline::first-line {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[text-decoration on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)
[::first-line on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line)

Comment: Sgnl, from the input from other people, the specs defines that behavior. Your solution, not perfect, works just in my case. Thanks!!!

Comment: yeah, its a hack for your case. Future readers: 'caveat emptor', YMMV, etc.

Answer (score 11):

This is actually the defined behavior in [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration):

> Text decorations draw across descendant elements. This means that it is not possible to disable on a descendant a text decoration that is specified on one of its ancestors.

More details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the specs! But it does not make sense if descendant text has to inherits text decoration from a parent tag and the specs also allows "text-decoration: none;" at the same time.

Comment: No, the specs make sense. You, as the developer, can add declarations any where you like, you can make all the declarations in the world but in the end will it work? Depends on specifications. Just because you can declare it doesn't necessarily mean it'll work.